# Reading huge data and keep updating histogram

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bigdata, histogram

I have huge amount of data stored in h5 files. Each file has ~1200 sub folders that have tables with ~65k columns. I need to put the data in a histogram and I don't know the range of data. Is there a way to read and populate histograms at the same time?

I tried adding data to an array but as you can see, the array has ~780M elements for 10 files:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        aiArr = []

        ### FILES                                                                                               
        for ff in range(0,10):
            f= h5py.File('/data/file'+str(ff)+'.h5','r')
            ### KEYS
            for i,key in enumerate(f.keys()):
                if ff==0 and i==0:
                   aiArr = np.array(f[key]['AI'][()])[0]
                else:
                   aiArr = np.append( aiArr , np.array(f[key]['AI'][()])[0] ,axis=0 )

         plt.hist(aiArr,bins='auto')                                          
         plt.savefig('hist_0.png')
```

As an alternative I made temporary histograms after `key` loop and then sum as
`hist_of_file += np.histogram(temp_hist,bins=bin_edges)` but it complains that `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1235,) (1234,)` and I had to define bin_edges after the first data entry. That is not ideal since the rest of the data can overflow it, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in memory-efficient way, but it will require two passes.
First, you should loop through your data and find minimal and maximal values. Then, choose number of bins for your histogram and calculate value ranges for each bin.

For example, if your data has range (0,100) and you want a 10-bin histogram, the ranges will be [[0.0,10.0],[10.0,20.0],...[90.0,100.0]]

Then you should create an integer array with length equal to the number of bins (this will be your histogram) and initialize it with zeros.

Then do the second loop, for each element of your data determine what bin it corresponds to and increment counter for that bin. In the end the histogram array will contain the data you require.